Odds vs Log(Odds)
I have precalculated Odds to run meta analysis. When I put data in formula, it analysis OR as logOR and changes my outcome. How to make formula accept Odds. Im using this formula (ill attach below), if you have any better suggestions for OR calculation Ill be happy to hear. Thank you
cvm <- metagen(TE= OR, lower = LL, upper = UL, sm = "OR",random = T, fixed = F, studlab = Author, data = CVM)
Its mentioned in question
